# Show colors from child shell in parent shell

Tags: shell-script, terminal, colors, control-characters

I solved this once, but I cannot remember how I did!

In my child process, I have this:

```
echo -e "some control chars"
```

In my parent process, it will show the plain string, without any terminal styling. Isn't there some way to interpret the control chars coming from stdout/stderr of child processes in the parent?

To be specific I have this bash function sourced in the parent:

```
ql_cyan='\033[1;36m'
ql_no_color='\033[0m'

function ql_log_colors {
    echo "sourcing quicklock.sh"
    echo -e "${ql_cyan}sourcing quicklock.sh${ql_no_color}";
    echo "${ql_cyan}sourcing quicklock.sh${ql_no_color}";
}

export -f ql_log_colors
```

if I run `ql_log_colors` in the current shell, I get colors!

however, if I call `ql_log_colors` from a subshell, no colors will be displayed in the parent, just the plain string "sourcing quicklock.sh".

As you can see, I tried 3 variants of echo command, all just output plain text in the parent, if the echo statements are called from a child.

Comment: Please [edit] in a working example illustrating the behaviour you're asking about.

Comment: sure I will add the actual control chars etc

Comment: added the edits which I think will help

Comment: I know it's possible to do this somehow, I just don't know how...using Node.js child processes, I have been able to show colors from the child when logging to the terminal from the parent..there's a flag or env variable or something to use.

Comment: You didn't export the variables and it's not a subshell you're running it from.

Comment: I see, so I need to export the `ql_cyan` and `ql_no_color` vars?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Frankly, I don't know what the difference is between subshell and child process, feel free to enlighten me